# How to clear existing setInterval?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have the code as below which used to start and stop a timer. It worked fine if click once on start and stop. How if I click the start for more than once and how do I stop the "previous created" setInterval?

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script>
         var myVar;

         function myStartFunction() {
             myVar = setInterval(function () {
                 myTimer();
             }, 1000);
         }

         function myTimer() {
             var d = new Date();
             var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
             document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
         }

         function myStopFunction() {
             clearInterval(myVar);
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p id="demo"></p>
      <button onclick="myStopFunction()">Stop time</button>
      <button onclick="myStartFunction()">Start time</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you seeing problems, at a glance it doesn't look like any errors should arise.

Comment: Seem you only need one timer, if myVar is valid, myStartFunction could just return;

Comment: Why not just `myVar = setInterval(myTimer);` instead of wrapping it?

Comment: @Andrew, please leave your suggested change on the answer as a comment.

Comment: see this: http://jsfiddle.net/3r48n/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value returned by `setInterval` is called a timer handle. If you want to be able to call "start" more than once and have multiple timers running at the same time, you need to save the handles in an array.

So for instance, if you want "stop" to stop the **last** timer you started:

```
var timers = [];

function myStartFunction() {
    timers.push(setInterval(function () {
        myTimer();
    }, 1000));
}

function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
}

function myStopFunction() {
    if (timers.length > 0) {
        clearInterval(timers.pop());
    }
}
```

---

Side note: You don't need the anonymous function in `myStartFunction`, you can just use `myTimer` directly:

```
function myStartFunction() {
    timers.push(setInterval(myTimer, 1000));
}
```

Comment: Why the wrapper instead of just using `setInterval(myTimer)`?

Comment: @6502: Because I was just doing the minimal mod of the OP's code. See the note at the end of the answer, though.

Comment: If that was present before then sorry but I didn't notice that part. If it wasn't present before then I just learned what is the **real** reason for continuously editing an answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

It should be like that.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script>
         function myStartFunction() {
             clearInterval(myTimer);
             setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
         }

         function myTimer() {
             var d = new Date();
             var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
             document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
         }

         function myStopFunction() {
             clearInterval(myTimer);
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p id="demo"></p>
      <button onclick="myStopFunction()">Stop time</button>
      <button onclick="myStartFunction()">Start time</button>
   </body>
</html>
```